# Iterate through html td's in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium

I have 2 test cases in which i want to select the html and need to get the values of all td's
1. Need to select the 2nd html displayed in the webpage and iterate through the td's and get the value 
2. Need to select the 3rd html displayed in the webpage and iterate through the td's and get the value.
Below is the html

```
<html> - 1st html in the page
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>..</td>
....
</tr>
.....
....
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>


<iframe> - Parent
<iframe tabindex="-1" frameborder="no" width="100%" src="about:blank" class="active">
<html>  - 2nd html in the page
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>..</td>
<td>..</td>
<td>..</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>..</td>
<td>..</td>
<td>..</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>..</td>
<td>..</td>
<td>..</td>
</tr>
....
....
.....
<tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>

<iframe tabindex="-1" frameborder="no" width="100%" src="about:blank" class="active">
<html> - 3rd html in the page
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>..</td>
<td>..</td>
<td>..</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>..</td>
<td>..</td>
<td>..</td>
</tr>
<tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</iframe>
```

FYI, I'm switching to the IFrame before finding the element

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(); - outerframe
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(); - InnerFrame
```

I tried the below one to find the element, but it is selecting the first html element on the webpage.

```
List<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/table/tbody")).FindElements(By.TagName("tr")).ToList();
```

Could anyone help me out on this?
Thanks

Comment: Yes you are on right track, you must switchToFrame to get to the other content.  I don't use XPATH ever.  I use for example currentElement.FindElements(By.Tagname("td"));  This shows me all TDs in the table if currentElement is the Table element or TableBody element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var frames = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe")).ToList()
    driver.switchTo().frames[1];
    tds = WebDriver.FindElements.(By.Tagname("td");;
    var td = tds.Where(ele=>ele.Text=="Something").ToList();
```

Comment: I'm already switching to the frame before finding the element like this driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src,'WorkflowActivities.aspx')]"))); - outerframe
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@id = 'ProxyPageRetriever']"))); - innerframe

Comment: Don't use XPATH use TagName  e.g. Webdriver.FindElements(By.Tagname("iframe")..  maybe that will work better for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The issue happens becasue the Xpath reside inside the iframe doesn't work.. I used CSS Selector instead of XPath..Now it works as expected

Comment: Yes css selector is what I use all the time instead of xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You should use code like below:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));
for(WebElement el: elements){
    String value = el.findElement(By.tagName(td)).getText();
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

While iterating frame td's you should select frame first then apply same as above code

Comment: driver.findElements(By.xpath("")) - What u r trying to say here?...Please read my que, I want to select only the 2nd html displayed on the webpage and iterating through the td's

Comment: Yes exactly I am saying same, second html comes under a frame, you should select frame first then, create xpath for tr and count how many tr there using findElements function, then you can iterate tr and find td value

Comment: findelements will return a collection. If i put the Xpath to select the html means it will give u the collection of result's not a particular one

Comment: Yes, it return List if all tr, then you can iterate one by one

Comment: Oh, you want to iterate td then you should create xpath for td.